# Using Dynamic SQL to reformat a table to having column names as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I've been stuck with this for a while and I've not found something on the website that answers something like this so please point me to the right direction if an existing question exists. In SQL Server 2012, I have a table with ID as the primary key:

```
ID      col1     col2   col3  ....
---   ----      -----   -----
1        a        z       k
2        g        b       p
3        k        d       a
```

I don't know the length of the table nor the amount of columns/ column names
but I want to be able to get a table that gives me something like:

```
ID     ColName  Value  
---   ----      -----  
1     col1      a 
1     col2      z
1     col3      k
2     col1      g
2     col2      b
2     col3      p
3     col1      k
3     col2      d
3     col3      a 
...
```

I know that

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
 TABLE_NAME = 'table'
```

gets me my columns and I've tried trying to use that to create a temp table to
insert my desired format into a temp table but I'm not sure how to go through each row in a table and then grab the desired values dynamically for each column name and display it. I've been able to kind of achieve this with double cursors but that is painfully slow and I'm not sure how else to approach this since I'm relatively new at SQL. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**

Thank you so very much Lamak! I did have varying data types and coverting them to varchars for now shows me that the concept does work. However, I have 4 common datatypes (varchar, float, int, datetime) that I want to account for so I have 4 value fields for each of those where I would insert the column value into one of those 4 depending on it and leave the other 3 blank. I know that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS also provides the data_types so I was wondering what the syntax would be to  convert the datatype in the "STUFF" variables based on a simple IF statement. I tried mapping the data_types to the column names but having any type of conditional statement breaks the query. If anyone has a simple example, that would be great :)

**Edit**
Actually, I've been able to figure out that I would need to create 4 variables to each data type rather than do them all in just one of them. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: There's a hundred examples on SO, but here is a [great step by step](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/). You are looking for "Dynamic Pivot"

Comment: @scsimon there are hundred of examples, but this is a "dynamic **unpivot**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments said, you'll need to use dynamic unpivot.

If every column aside `ID` have the same datatype, you can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @colsUnpivot = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(C.name)
                             FROM sys.columns as C
                             WHERE C.object_id = object_id('table') AND
                                   C.name <> 'ID'
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = '
SELECT  ID, 
        ColName, 
        Value
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.table
) x
UNPIVOT
(
  Value FOR ColName IN (' + @colsunpivot + ')
) u
';

EXEC(@query);
```

Now, if the datatypes are different, then you'll need to first convert every column to a common datatype. In the following example, I'll use `NVARCHAR(1000)`, but you'll need to convert them to the right datatype:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @colsUnpivot2 as  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @colsUnpivot1 = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(C.name)
                             FROM sys.columns as C
                             WHERE C.object_id = object_id('table') AND
                                   C.name <> 'ID'
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @colsUnpivot2 = STUFF((SELECT ', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1000),' + QUOTENAME(C.name)
                                     + ') ' + QUOTENAME(C.name)
                             FROM sys.columns as C
                             WHERE C.object_id = object_id('table') AND
                                   C.name <> 'ID'
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = '
SELECT  ID, 
        ColName, 
        Value
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, ' + @colsUnpivot2 + '
  FROM dbo.table
) x
UNPIVOT
(
  Value FOR ColName IN ('+ @colsunpivot1 +')
) u
';

EXEC(@query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go DYNAMIC.   Another Option with with a CROSS APPLY and a little XML.

UnPivot is more performant, but you will find the performance of this approach very respectable.

An added bonus of this approach is that the `From @YourTable A` could be any query (not limited to a table).  For example `From ( -- Your Complex Query --) A`

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Col1 varchar(25),Col2 varchar(25),Col3 varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'a','z','k')
,(2,'g','b','p')
,(3,'k','d','a')


Select C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select ID     = r.value('@ID','int')
                      ,Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','OtherFieldsToExclude')
             ) C
```

Returns

```
ID  Item    Value
1   Col1    a
1   Col2    z
1   Col3    k
2   Col1    g
2   Col2    b
2   Col3    p
3   Col1    k
3   Col2    d
3   Col3    a
```